# works on commandline directly, but complaints syntax error when aliased in bash

Tags: bash, alias

Here's the command, I am trying to run on bash, it works great. But when I aliased and put in the bashrc, it complaints of a syntax error.

```
  alias dsh="for i in `ls -d */`;do echo $i; du -sh $i;done"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to use single quotes. Otherwise `ls -d */` and `$i` get's expanded in the shell where you define the alias, not in the shell where you execute that alias.

```
alias dsh='for i in `ls -d */`;do echo "$i"; du -sh "$i";done'
```

However, iterating over the results of `ls` is not recommended. If a folder name returned by ls contains spaces, the `for i in` loop wouldn't handle it properly. That's why I suggest to use `find`

```
alias dsh='find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -sh {} \;'
```

Note that `du -sh` will print the folder name. No further echo is required.

---

tripleee posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33721948/171318) here showing that using `find` is a bit too complicated. He suggests to use `du -sh */`. This looks like the best approach for me. I would go with it.

Answer (score 4):

Inside double quotes, the command substitution in backticks will get evaluated by the shell immediately. The obvious workaround is to switch to single quotes, which inhibit this. But you can avoid the backticks and the [useless `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls) with the simpler and more elegant `for i in */`.

However, you don't need a loop here at all; like most Unix utilities which take file name arguments, du accepts an arbitrary number of them: `du -sh */`

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes and also instead of `ls -d */` use just `*/`:

```
alias dsh='for i in */;do echo "$i"; du -sh "$i"; done'
```